# upserting sqlite fails with a syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

Given the SQLite table

```
CREATE TABLE            users (

       username         TEXT NOT NULL,
       hashed_password  TEXT NOT NULL,
       disabled         INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
       updated_at       DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

       UNIQUE(username)
) ;
```

and a query

```
Q = {
    "sqlite": {
        "upsert_user": """ INSERT INTO users(username, hashed_password, disabled, updated_at) VALUES(?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ON CONFLICT(username) DO UPDATE SET hashed_password=?, disabled=?, updated_at=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP """
    }
}
```

and a tuple that describes a user

```
user = ('awesome-username',
 '$2b$12$55Nkrpw2Gz3p4yg8gD8XS.EmLOOdE5W3Hj3rkzmAsMrAYMm.swwfq',
 0,
 '$2b$12$55Nkrpw2Gz3p4yg8gD8XS.EmLOOdE5W3Hj3rkzmAsMrAYMm.swwfq',
 0)
```

when I try to upsert/insert the `user`

```
with db_conn as conn:
                                    conn.execute(
                                        Q["sqlite"]["upsert_user"],
                                        (
                                            username,
                                            hashed_password,
                                            0,
                                            hashed_password,
                                            0,
                                        )
                                    )
```

It fails with an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-13-63b5a41b8c7f>", line 43, in is_user_identity_managed
    1
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ON": syntax error
```

Please note that I paste the raw query in SQLite, it succeeds.

My mind is going to explode figuring out why the above fails in Python, could you please advise ?

Comment: I think you're looking for INSERT OR REPLACE but you'll need to set one of the columns as UNIQUE (`username` I guess). `""" INSERT OR REPLACE INTO users(username, hashed_password, disabled, updated_at) VALUES(?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`

Comment: I am not looking for `INSERT OR REPLACE` since `UPSERT` is supported in SQLite https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html the table definition is pasted above and it does have the `UNIQUE` constraint

Comment: From the page you linked to:  "UPSERT syntax was added to SQLite with version 3.24.0 (2018-06-04)".  If it works in one console/program but not another, first check the sqlite version.

Comment: yes the raw SQL query succeeds as mentioned above`$ sqlite3 --version
3.29.0 2019-07-10 17:32:03 fc82b73eaac8b36950e527f12c4b5dc1e147e6f4ad2217ae43ad82882a88bfa6`

Comment: @onedreamcloser  I think you missed the point.  You verified the version of only the sqlite which succeeds.  The intention was for you to check the **version of sqlite installed with python** since that is the failing code.